# How can I dump tab completion output (typically below the cli cursor) to file?

Tags: autocomplete, zsh, tab-completion

Is there a way to dump the tab text to a file or piped to less?  For example at the command line you might type `%>git <TAB>` and it will output a list of subcommands if you are using common zsh completions.

The list can vary based on any current zstyle settings.  But in general the output to the terminal below the cursor is what I'm referring to.

How can I dump tab completion output (typically below the cli cursor) to file?